# How do I show all day appointments in day, but hide them in work week in Outlook 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, calendar

I've made two views, one showing all day appointments and one not showing them. I want to have the view showing all day appointments when switching to day view, but when switching to work week or month, I want to switch to the view not showing those all day appointments. How do I do that

Alternatively, is there a way I can reduce the size of the part of the days that shows all day appointments?

Am I just missing something? It does not make sense that I can define different views, but not set a default view for each arrangement separately.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Day/Week/Month are just arrangements of a single view, not separate views. So, you can filter out all day appointments by using Advanced Filter (**All Day Event** *not equal* **Yes**), but this will apply to all arrangements.

Alternatively, you can create to "Day/Week/Month" views, one that filters All Day Events and one that not.

VBA way. You'll need to create a separate view for each of the arrangements (in the sample below, these are views named "Days", "Weeks" and "Months"):

```vb
Public WithEvents OutlookExplorer As Outlook.Explorer

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set OutlookExplorer = ActiveExplorer
End Sub

Private Sub OutlookExplorer_ViewSwitch()
    Set View = OutlookExplorer.CurrentView
    If View.ViewType = 2 Then
        If View.Name = "Days" And View.CalendarViewMode <> 0 Then
            View.CalendarViewMode = 0
            View.Save
        ElseIf View.Name = "Weeks" And View.CalendarViewMode <> 1 Then
            View.CalendarViewMode = 1
            View.Save
        ElseIf View.Name = "Months" And View.CalendarViewMode <> 2 Then
            View.CalendarViewMode = 2
            View.Save
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Now, the correct arrangement will be applied automatically when switching to the one of the custom views ("Days", "Weeks" or "Months"). Additionally, you can place the "Change View" button right on "Home" tab on your calendar ribbon.

Comment: I made two views so far. I thought maybe of writing a macro that switches between them when switching between day and week arrangement. Is that possible in Outlook (I know you can write macros in Outlook, I just don't have a clue as to the capabilities there)? Would such a macro burden Outlook heavily or would it still run decently?

Comment: You can't do it this way because you need ViewSwitch event and Outlook doesn't fire it when changing arrangements. But what you can do is to create a separate view for each of the arrangements and apply the arrangements automatically (see updated answer).